# php7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 using ppa:ondrej/php wants to install apache2 on upgrade

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I wanted to install php7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 using the following ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-fpm
```

So far it worked flawlessly, but when I do `apt upgrade` now it forces me to install `apache2-bin` and `php8.0`, which I do not want as I am using Nginx.

How can I upgrade now without installing new packages I do not want?

Answer (score 0):

`apt upgrade` install(update) also dependenc packages.. try upgrade manually `sudo apt --only-upgrade install Package` or use `apt-mark hold Package` - this will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed

[original source](https://linoxide.com/exclude-specific-package-apt-get-upgrade/)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I tried to hold apache2 and php8, but after every upgrade it gets reset. Now I have to hold it everytime I want to upgrade. How can I find out which updated packet from ondrejs ppa is requesting php8 and apache2?